# bazel build hanging on "Fetching repository @local_jdk"

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

I'm new to Bazel. I installed it using "brew install baselisk", as recommended [by the official Bazel docs](https://bazel.build/install/bazelisk). `bazel --version` gives `bazel 6.1.2`. I then followed [the official bazel Java tutorial](https://bazel.build/start/java), but when I did "bazel build", it said the following for more than 500 seconds, and my 14in m1 pro macbook pro actually started getting hot for the very first time since I bought it 1.5 years ago.

```
$ bazel build //:ProjectRunner
Analyzing: target //:ProjectRunner (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    Fetching repository @local_jdk; starting 550s
```

I have openjdk 20 and macOS 13.3.1

Am I doing something wrong? Does Bazel not support JDK 20? What is actually hanging there? Is it trying to download its own version of JDK or something like that?

Comment: Recent support is added [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/18028). But did you see the same error with older jdk versions?

Comment: I never tried using older jdk versions with Bazel.